# C++/ SystemC : Is there a way to select only a range of values from array? ( For example selecting 5 values from an array of 10 values)

Tags: c++, systemc

OK here's what I am trying. I have passed an array to a function. And while returning I want to send in only those values which are defined in a array. For example, say I have an array definition of 10, I want to return only 5 values from that array, in the function.

Any suggestions!? Thanks.

Sample Code:

```
sc_uint<8> *arrayfill(struct){
sc_uint<8> array[10];

array[1] = struct.a;
array[2] = struct.b;
...
if (struct.trigger == false){
  array[10] =0;
}
else 
{
  array[10] = struct.j;
}

return array;
}
```

So now here is the thing, I want to return only upto 9 values of array when struct.trigger is false, else I am returning all the values of array. And this is where I am unable to find a solution.

Comment: The first five? Five picked at random? Five that meet certain criteria? And please show some code.

Comment: @Biffen: Its the five that meet a random criteria..!!! I'll put in a sample code below!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use the array reference as the in and out parameters, and extract 5 elements from the in array, and then put it into the out array.
Like:

```
void ExtrctElemnts(const std::vector<int>& in_array, std::vector<int>& out_array){
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
          out_array.push_back(in_array.at(i));
     }
}
```

Of course, you can also choose specific elements of the in array.

Comment: @Yu hao: Thanks for your suggestion, but guess that might be the solution for my answer. Please refer the code above for my problem.